# Disjunction of filters in ajax, request to flask-restless

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a backend application with [flask-restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchformat.html#examples) which replies some json data. It is properly set.
I request these data from javascript by $.ajax function. It works perfect with one filter, I need more filters, but I don't know how them set.

Example with one filter (it works):

```
    var page = 1;
    var filters = [{"name": "device", "op": "eq", "val": 1}];       

    var url = 'http://..../results?page=' + page;

            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: {"q": JSON.stringify({"filters": filters})},
              dataType: "jsonp",
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/jsonp",
              success: function(responseData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {...}
            });
```

For 2 filters I tried (it doesn't work):

```
    var page = 1;
    var filters = [{"name": "device", "op": "eq", "val": 1},{"name": "device", "op": "eq", "val": 2}];      

    var url = 'http://..../results?page=' + page;

        $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: {"q": JSON.stringify({"filters": filters},{"disjunction":true})},
              dataType: "jsonp",
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/jsonp",
              success: function(responseData, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {...}
         });
```

Has anyone of you ever had similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give JSON.stringify an array to convert to string.

```
data: {"q": JSON.stringify([{"filters": filters},{"disjunction":true}])},
```